# Atualizei o build gradle para a versão 7.2, logo apos recebi o seguinte problema, como posso resolver?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' (type 'FlutterTask').
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'assets' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'assetsDirectory' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'buildMode' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'fastStart' doesn't have a configured value.

    Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Assign a value to 'fastStart'.
      2. Mark property 'fastStart' as optional.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#value_not_set for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'flutterExecutable' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Isto está acontecendo porque você atualizou o gradle em seu projeto para o gradle > 7. E o gradle > 7 tem uma nova propriedade de anotação que deve ser revisada.

Você pode escolher estas duas opções para solução do seu problema:

1 - Faça o downgrade do seu gradle para versões < 7.

2 - Faça as alterações mencionadas neste [link.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/79167/files)

*Na página referida (Pull Request). Há uma seção chamada Files Changed. Veja as linhas de cor verde. Basta editar seu arquivo gradle e adicionar/editar as linhas verdes.*